# Vuex: How to subscribe to event from action

Tags: events, vuex, store

I'm pretty new in Vuex, and want I want to do it's quite simple, but I don't know what is the best pattern used by typical Vuex code.

I have an action that initializes and stores a `Machine` object which also can emit status events which I would like to suscribe and get notified on by  store users.

e.g: This action is defined by :

```
createMachine({ commit, state }) {
      return state.m.createMachine().then(
        function (machineObject) {
          commit('setMachine', machineObject);
         }
      )
    }
```

I want to listen to the created `machineObject` object events from inside the store, and eventually update a store variable that I can watch from components by using something like:

```
computed: { getMachineStatus() { return this.$store.state.machineStatus } }
```

Did i make it clear?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Vuex has subscribeAction methhod,
see [vuex.subscribeAction](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribeaction)

```
store.subscribeAction((action, state) => {
    console.log(action.type);
    console.log(action.payload);

    if (action.type === 'createMachine') {
        // do what you want there
    }
});
```

Comment: Action.type always show the action name of vuex store  ?